# 2.91 fluid sim, renders w/o fluid

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a fluid sim that is baked and looks good when I play it, my water flows nicely.  When I attempt to render it to png as a series for future image sequence, the water does not even show up.  This must be a simple problem on my part.  None of the fluid sim videos seems to have any issues like this.  I reviewed and reviewed and searched, to no avail.  Help is appreciated!  [image]
[image]

Comment: the best help you will get if you provide your blend file. Normally this happens if you didn't setup your material in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you turn off the render in the outliner tab?

[image]